# Data is not saved promptly on realtime-database firebase

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm coding my register function and when i register succesfully, it will turn back to the page menu(index.html). And I using firebase to store my data. But i have a problem that when it turn back to the index.html, Data is only stored in the authentication segment, but not in the realtime database. I think it's because it hasn't been transferred yet. Then it performed the command to return to the previous page. I researched that I should use async but when I added it it was still the same.

i have try using aysnc but don't know what wrong

```js
async function register() {
  full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;
  email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
  phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;

  if (password != confirm_password) {
    alert('difference password');
    return;
  }
  if (valid_name(full_name) == false) {
    alert('invalid name');
    return;
  }
  if (valid_email(email) == false || valid_password(password) == false) {
    alert('Email or Password is not valid');
    return;
  }
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function () {
    var user = auth.currentUser;
    var database_ref = database.ref();
    var userID = phone_number;

    var user_data = {
      full_name: full_name,
      phone_number: phone_number,
      email: email,
    };

    database_ref.child('Register/' + userID).set(user_data);
    alert('user created !');
  });
}

function checkLoginStatus() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function (user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log('User is signed in.');
      await register();
      window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else {
      console.log('No user is signed in.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why `checkLoginStatus()` registers an auth state listener that runs `register()` when a user **exists**. It doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix async / await with `.then()`, it just leads to confusing code.

You're not waiting for either `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` or `set(user_data)` to complete before navigating.

Using `alert()` to signify failed states will also not prevent navigation. You should throw errors instead so the `register()` promise fails.

Simplify your code by only using `await`

```js
async function register() {
  const full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  const confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
  const phone_number = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;

  if (password != confirm_password) {
    throw new Error('difference password');
  }
  if (valid_name(full_name) == false) {
    throw new Error('invalid name');
  }
  if (valid_email(email) == false || valid_password(password) == false) {
    throw new Error('Email or Password is not valid');
  }

  // not sure why you even want / need `user` but anyway
  const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  var userID = phone_number;

  var user_data = { full_name, phone_number, email };

  await database
    .ref()
    .child('Register/' + userID)
    .set(user_data);

  //alert('user created !');
}
```